# Javascript format a decimal number to tree numbers after decimal

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

How can I format numbers like

```
0.00012006 to 0.00012
0.00004494 to 0.0000449
0.000000022732 to 0.0000000227 without becoming a number like 2.3e-8
```

I would like to know how I can change numbers like that in a fast/efficient way. 
I would like to know how to convert those numbers but if someone knows how to format it only like that, I would like to know that too.

Comment: how this numbers `0.100101`, `0.1100001`, `1.000001` should be converted?

Answer (score 0):

You coud get the places of the number and add 2 on it for `toFixed`.

```js
function three(v) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.log(v) / Math.LN10);
    return v.toFixed(n < 2 ? 2 - n : 0);
}

var n = [0.00012006, 0.00004494, 0.000000022732, 0.100101, 0.1100001, 1.000001, 12000, 10, 1e10];

console.log(n.map(three));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourNumber.toFixed(numberOfDigitsAfterDot)` like this:

```js
function format(n) {
  var _n = n;
  // count the position of the first decimal
  var count = 0;
  do {
    n = n * 10;
    count++;
  } while(n < 1);
  return _n.toFixed(count + 2);
}


var num = 0.000000022732;

console.log(format(num));
```